# Created UItextfield programmatically, how to get text later in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I made a UITextField programmatically in the viewDidAppear class as shown below:

```
let userfield: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500.00, height: 30.00));
userfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
userfield.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
userfield.keyboardType = .emailAddress
userfield.placeholder = "Email"
view.addSubview(userfield)
```

The text field shows with no problems, however, when I try to call it in another function:

```
@objc func buttonregisteraction(sender: UIButton!) {
    if let username = userfield.text, let password = password.text
```

I get this error : "Unresolved Identifier 'userfield' "

I have seen the same question, but only in Objective-C.

Comment: what is wrong? Provide more details.

Comment: That is my property declaration.

Comment: if you declared it inside `viewDidAppear()` it will not be available outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `userfield` as a variable that is only available inside `viewDidAppear`. You need to make it a property of the view controller.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var userfield: UITextField! // declare it here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userfield = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500.00, height: 30.00));
        userfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        userfield.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        userfield.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        userfield.placeholder = "Email"
        view.addSubview(userfield)
    }
}
```

Now you can access `userfield` from any method in your view controller including your button action.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

use this code for text field and properties. you can add more property.

```
lazy var textExample: UITextField = {
        let textFiled = UITextField()
        textFiled.text = "how you doing man?"
        textFiled.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30)
        textFiled.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        textFiled.textAlignment = .left
        textFiled.textColor = .blue
        textFiled.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        textFiled.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return textFiled
    }()
```

then just add in view like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
```

hope this was simply enough :)